# Open an existing folder/directory using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a `python` program which has many buttons for various operations like opening camera , flash on and off , in `rasberrypi`.Now i'm trying to open a directory which contains all the captured images,using the default file explorer in pi,i've tried `os.path` open but it only opens up specific files and not directory , So if anyone knows how to open a directory , please help me , Thank you

```
import os
def Openfolder():
  open("/home/pi/Desktop/Images/")
```

the error im getting is   [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/pi/Desktop/Images/'

to do this in windows there are some options like explorer(path) which opens the folder , how to do it in rasberry pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double slashes for directories

```
import os
def Openfolder():
    open("//home//pi//Desktop//Images//")
```

Answer (score 7):

The file explorer can be opened by:

```
webbrowser.open("//home//pi//Desktop//Images//")
```